# Wrap content from every time a class appears - Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to wrap my a div around my li tags every time I add a li.gsection to the form.

1. Is it possible to wrap automatically like this? I know how to wrap and wrapAll manually, but that's a whole different thing.
2. The third class is always my custom class. I want it to be added to the wrapper and then add _comtainer to it.
3. This is a luxury problem but. The form uses ajax, can this be loaded even though I use a multipart form? A form with several pages in steps?

I'm a little lost and new to this site, but let me know if I have to do something first.

Keviin.

I have this markup in my form

```
<ul>
    <li class="gform gsection info random-class">Title</li>
    <li class="random-class">Name</li>
    <li class="random-class">Email</li>
    <li class="random-class">Phone</li>
    <li class="gform gsection more_info random-class">Title again</li>
    <li class="random-class">Something</li>
    <li class="random-class">Something</li>
    <li class="random-class">Something</li>
    <li class="gform gsection last_info random-class">Title again</li>
    <li class="random-class">Something</li>
    <li class="random-class">Something</li>
</ul>
```

I want this:

```
<ul>
    <ul class="section info_container">
        <li class="gform gsection info random-class">Title</li>
        <li class="random-class">Name</li>
        <li class="random-class">Email</li>
        <li class="random-class">Phone</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="section more_info_container">
        <li class="gform gsection more_info random-class">Title again</li>
        <li class="random-class">Something</li>
        <li class="random-class">Something</li>
        <li class="random-class">Something</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="section last_info_container">
        <li class="gform gsection last_info random-class">Title again</li>
        <li class="random-class">Something</li>
        <li class="random-class">Something</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please note that in order to have valid HTML markup, `ul` elements can only have `li` elements as direct children.

Comment: Thanks for that... Can i have another ul inside the li?

Comment: Yes, that is perfectly valid for multi-level lists.

Comment: I'll change my html structure.. Do you know f my question is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off simply faking this with CSS:

```css
li {
  list-style: circle;
  margin-left: 3em
}

li.gsection {
  list-style: disc;
  margin-left: 0
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="gform gsection info random-class">Title</li>
  <li class="random-class">Name</li>
  <li class="random-class">Email</li>
  <li class="random-class">Phone</li>
  <li class="gform gsection more_info random-class">Title again</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="gform gsection last_info random-class">Title again</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
</ul>
```

...but if you really need to restructure the DOM, here's one approach: it works by finding the index of each `.gsection` list item, scanning ahead to find the index of the next one, and wrapping that group in a new `ul`.

```js
var refactor = function(parent) {
  var lis = parent.find('li');
  for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
    if ($(lis[i]).hasClass('gsection')) {
      // found a header, read the relevant classname:
      var headerClass = "";
      if ($(lis[i]).hasClass('info')) {
        headerClass = "info_container"
      } else if ($(lis[i]).hasClass('more_info')) {
        headerClass = "more_info_container"
      } else if ($(lis[i]).hasClass('last_info')) {
        headerClass = "last_info_container"
      }

      // scan ahead until we find the next header:
      var j = i+1;
      while (j < lis.length) {
        if ($(lis[j]).hasClass('gsection')) break;
        j++
      }
      lis.slice(i+1, j).wrapAll("<ul class='section "+headerClass+"'>");
      i = j-1; // no need to iterate over the elements we just scanned past
    }
  }
}

refactor($('ul'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="gform gsection info random-class">Title</li>
  <li class="random-class">Name</li>
  <li class="random-class">Email</li>
  <li class="random-class">Phone</li>
  <li class="gform gsection more_info random-class">Title again</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="gform gsection last_info random-class">Title again</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
  <li class="random-class">Something</li>
</ul>
```

> The form uses ajax, can this be loaded even though I use a multipart form? A form with several pages in steps?

This will depend on how exactly those parts are broken up, but in general assuming you run this on each part's list after it is inserted into the DOM, it should work (except for sub-lists that span across more than one part.)

Comment: Thanks Daniel :) I'll try it.. Two things:..... 1st: can the header class be added automaticly?........ 2nd: can you wrap the li tag with the title so it's going into the ul too?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "can the header class be added automatically".  If you want to include the title items in the child `<ul>`s, you can change the index of the elements you use wrapAll on (i.e. `lis.slice(i, j)` instead of `lis.slice(i+1, j)`. (But that leaves nothing in the parent `<ul>`, which makes me wonder why split them into sub-lists in the first place?)

Comment: It's a plugin which creates the list and i can't control it. That's why i'm asking for it.____ And your code works so good.. Now i can create section in my form and make a card based layout. One card with multiple item.. The reason i wan't to auto add the third class to the parent ul is so i from the backend can add catogories.___ Ex. Information, Feedback, Submit. but if i add anothe gsection in the backend i have to go back to the script every time to add the ehader class.. So difficult for me to explain..

Comment: Btw.. thanks tou you i can start design cards like this (example):https://sharex.cadima.io/chrome_2018-06-16_20-03-07.png